# Is unnecessarily staying in a more expensive hotel and charging it to my employer a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

My work usually pays for my accommodation as I travel.  Ordinarily, I stay in the cheapest possible place (e.g. backpackers), but sometimes I stay in more expensive places even though it's not strictly necessary.  There'll be some justifications, e.g. the conference will be more convenient to get to; I didn't have time to optimize my bookings; I don't want to make my lab look like it's "cheap"; to avoid staying in mixed-gender accommodation.

**Question**: Is unnecessarily staying in a more expensive hotel and charging it to my employer a sin?

Depending on how you look at it, this resembles "theft"---I could send a smaller bill to my employer by staying at lower quality accommodation.  My employer is not going to get grumpy at me (usually others stay in nicer accommodation than I require).

Comment: I think staying at a backpacker's is not an appropriate accommodation for a Muslim woman. You should stay at a safer place which is convenient and comfortable for you. There is normally a certain standard employers need to provide when the employee is obliged to travel and stay over night.

Comment: Most employer's have a fixed stipend allocated for their employees which varies depending on the person's role and experience. If not used fully by the department, many a times the management tends to reduce the overall budget of the whole department. As long as you don't cross the stipend limits agreed to by you and the employer, you would be doing your duty as an employee by being a good brand ambassador for the company and completing the tasks assigned. How is that 'unnecessary expenditure'?

Answer (score 0):

In any country we'd call this thing "free-loading", but if I assume you told the employer and got consent it would be all halal for you.

Though if it is unnecessarily lavish then it may not be the best option because everything you get from Allah will be questioned and the fact that this money doesn't belong to you.

Though I'm sure if you choose the lower accommodations due to Taqwa and fear of god then the reward will be greater then what ever you can find on earth.

> **AND ALLAH KNOWS BEST, MAY ALLAH FORGIVE ME FOR ANY MISTAKES**